# How to use ID or resource ID contains locator for Android in WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, appium, webdriver-io, appium-android

I have a Android Native UI where I have:

1. Find By: id, Selector: 76ggg-unique-ID-o9o
2. Attribute - class: android.view.ViewGroup
3. resource-id: 76ggg-unique-ID-o9o

Now I want to create a selector for this element in [WebdriverIO](https://webdriver.io/docs/selectors/) where I can use contains unique-ID. I tried following but nothing worked.

```
'strategy': 'css selector',
'strategyVal': '[id*="unique-ID"]'
```

```
'strategy': 'css selector',
'strategyVal': '[id*=unique-ID]'
```

```
'strategy': 'xpath',
'strategyVal': '//*[contains(@id, "unique-ID")]'
```

```
'strategy': 'xpath',
'strategyVal': '//*[@id*="unique-ID"]'
```

```
'strategy': 'xpath',
'strategyVal': '//*[contains(@id, "unique-ID")]'
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some debugging I came to know it was taking some time to load UI. After waiting for few seconds, below locator strategy worked.

```
'strategy': 'xpath',
'strategyVal': '//android.view.ViewGroup[contains(@resource-id, "unique-ID")]'
```

Comment: This also works and is a bit simpler: `//*[@resource-id="unique-ID"]`